# Error running iOS simulator after adding firestore dependency following the Firebase for Flutter tutorial

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, ios-simulator, flutter-dependencies

I've been following a couple of flutter tutorials and most recently tried following the Firebase for Flutter tutorial which can be found here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/

I created a new project like the tutorial says, test ran it on both android and iOS and it worked fine. Then I added **cloud_firestore: ^0.8.0** to the pubspec.yaml file and ran "Packages get" just like the tutorial says.

Now whenever I try to run the project in an iOS simulator I get the following error:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001140b329b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011364f735 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001140b30f5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   Runner                              0x000000010f364441 +[FIRApp configure] + 481
4   Runner                              0x000000010f6bd02c -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 188
5   Runner                              0x000000010f6bced9 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 297
6   Runner                              0x000000010f30c73b +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 123
7   Runner                        <…>
```

The tutorial describes a different problem that can happen with simulating on iOS. I've followed the solution for that issue (changing the build system to Legacy Build System) but that did not change anything regarding my problem.

I have tried finding solutions to this problem online but without any luck. Do you have any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase needed to be added to the folder /ios/Runner.

More info here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22536?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Dandido's answer:

In the tutorial you mentioned you first can run your project on ios devices after you completed part 7 "Platform-specific Firebase configuration". In that step, you will create a GoogleService-Info.plist and add it to your Xcode project.